# Adding vertical and horizontal lines between rows and columns

Tags: python, tkinter, grid

I want to add vertical and horizontal lines , preferably with a color option that I choose, between the rows and columns of my gui. I tried asking around but haven't gotten an answer that helped me.

I tried a few methods like tk separator but no luck, I'd really love for an answer as this it the only problem that I have.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

# Function to add items to the Treeview
def add_items():
    tree.insert("", "end", values=("EUW", "JD123", "Gold"))
    tree.insert("", "end", values=("EUNE", "JS456", "Silver"))
    tree.insert("", "end", values=("TR", "AJ789", "Bronze"))

# Function to sort by Region column
def sort_by_region():
    data = [(tree.set(child, "Region"), child) for child in tree.get_children("") if tree.parent(child) == ""]
    data.sort()  # Sort the data by Region
    for index, (region, child) in enumerate(data):
        tree.move(child, "", index)  # Move the sorted rows

# Function to sort by Username column
def sort_by_username():
    data = [(tree.set(child, "Username"), child) for child in tree.get_children("") if tree.parent(child) == ""]
    data.sort()  # Sort the data by Username
    for index, (username, child) in enumerate(data):
        tree.move(child, "", index)  # Move the sorted rows

# Function to sort by Rank column
def sort_by_rank():
    data = [(tree.set(child, "Rank"), child) for child in tree.get_children("") if tree.parent(child) == ""]
    data.sort()  # Sort the data by Rank
    for index, (rank, child) in enumerate(data):
        tree.move(child, "", index)  # Move the sorted rows

# Create the main window
root = tk.Tk()
root.title("LOL Account Manager")
root.geometry("740x370")
root.configure(bg="#282e48")

# Create a Frame for the Treeview
frame = tk.Frame(root)
frame.pack(fill="both", expand=True, padx=10, pady=10)

# Create a Treeview with columns
tree = ttk.Treeview(frame, columns=("Region", "Username", "Rank"), show="headings", height=18)

# Define column headings
tree.heading("Region", text="Region", command=sort_by_region)
tree.heading("Username", text="Username", command=sort_by_username)
tree.heading("Rank", text="Rank", command=sort_by_rank)

# Define column widths
tree.column("Region", width=200)
tree.column("Username", width=200)
tree.column("Rank", width=200)

# Add items to the Treeview
add_items()

# Hotkey function for reloading items
def reload_items(event):
    for item in tree.get_children():
        tree.delete(item)
    add_items()

root.bind("<Control-r>", reload_items)

# Configure the style for the Treeview
style = ttk.Style()
style.theme_use("default")

# Configure Treeview's borders for white gridlines
style.configure("Treeview.Heading", background="#282e48", foreground="#FFFFFF")
style.configure("Treeview", background="#282e48", foreground="#FFFFFF", fieldbackground="#282e48", bordercolor="#FFFFFF", borderwidth=1)
style.map("Treeview.Heading", background=[('active', '#282e48'), ('!active', '#282e48')])  # Prevent color change on hover

# Pack the Treeview
tree.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

# Update the window to get proper dimensions
root.update_idletasks()

# Calculate the screen width and height
screen_width = root.winfo_screenwidth()
screen_height = root.winfo_screenheight()

# Calculate the position to center the window
x_coordinate = int((screen_width - root.winfo_width()) / 2)
y_coordinate = int((screen_height - root.winfo_height()) / 2)

# Set the window to be centered
root.geometry(f"+{x_coordinate}+{y_coordinate}")

root.mainloop()
```